# Access dataset in RecyclerView adapter from activity

Tags: android

From my activity I have a list of data which I pass into a RecyclerView adapter. The adapter takes the list of data and manipulates during user interaction.

Now I want to access the dataset in the adapter to use in my activity, so that when the user rotates their device or for any other reason the activity is destroyed and recreated, the dataset from the adapter can be saved in the activity and then passed back into the adapter when the activity is created again.

How would this be possible? RecyclerView adapter doesn't have methods for getting items from the dataset like a typical adapter.

My adapter code:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyCustomAdapter.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener,
    EditText.OnEditorActionListener {

private ArrayList<Task> mDataset;
private static Context sContext;

// Adapter's Constructor
public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Task> myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
    sContext = context;
}

// Create new views. This is invoked by the layout manager.
@Override
public MyCustomAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // Create a new view by inflating the item_row.xml
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);

    // Set the view to the ViewHolder
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(v);
    holder.myCheckBox.setOnClickListener(MyCustomAdapter.this);
    holder.myItem.setOnEditorActionListener(MyCustomAdapter.this);

    holder.myRow.setTag(holder);
    holder.myCheckBox.setTag(holder);
    holder.myItem.setTag(holder);

    return holder;
}

// Replace the contents of a view. This is invoked by the layout manager.
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Task task = mDataset.get(position);
    holder.myItem.setText(task.getName());
    if (task.isCompleted()) {
        holder.myCheckBox.setChecked(true);
        holder.myItem.setPaintFlags(holder.myItem.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        holder.myItem.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#8C000000"));
    }
    else {
        holder.myCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        holder.myItem.setPaintFlags( holder.myItem.getPaintFlags() & (~ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG) );
        holder.myItem.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#E6000000"));
    }
}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}

// Implement OnClick listener.
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    if (holder.myCheckBox.isChecked()) {
        Task task = mDataset.get(holder.getPosition());
        task.setCompleted(true);
        mDataset.set(holder.getPosition(), task);
    }
    else {
        Task task = mDataset.get(holder.getPosition());
        task.setCompleted(false);
        mDataset.set(holder.getPosition(), task);
    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

            if (view.getText().length() != 0) {
                Task task = mDataset.get(holder.getPosition());
                task.setName(view.getText().toString());
                mDataset.set(holder.getPosition(), task);

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                view.setText("");
            }

            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Create the ViewHolder class to keep references to your views
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public LinearLayout myRow;
    public CheckBox myCheckBox;
    public EditText myItem;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param v The container view which holds the elements from the item_row.xml
     */
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        myRow = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.item_row);
        myCheckBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.myCheckBox);
        myItem = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.myItem);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can create a cutom adapter and add a get() and set() methods  to your data

Comment: My current adapter is already a custom adapter. So are you saying that I need to set it as abstract and then create a new adapter which extends it?

Comment: No. post your adapter code, i'll tell you what you should do

Comment: I've added my adapter code to my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyCustomAdapter.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener,
    EditText.OnEditorActionListener {

private ArrayList<Task> mDataset;
private static Context sContext;

// Adapter's Constructor
public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Task> myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
    sContext = context;
}

public ArrayList<Task> getDataSet(){
 return mDataset;
}

public void setDataSet(ArrayList<Task> newDataSet){
 this.mDataset = newDataSet;
 notifyDataSetChanged();
}


// Create new views. This is invoked by the layout manager.
@Override
public MyCustomAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // Create a new view by inflating the item_row.xml
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);

    // Set the view to the ViewHolder
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(v);
    holder.myCheckBox.setOnClickListener(MyCustomAdapter.this);
    holder.myItem.setOnEditorActionListener(MyCustomAdapter.this);

    holder.myRow.setTag(holder);
    holder.myCheckBox.setTag(holder);
    holder.myItem.setTag(holder);

    return holder;
}

// Replace the contents of a view. This is invoked by the layout manager.
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Task task = mDataset.get(position);
    holder.myItem.setText(task.getName());
    if (task.isCompleted()) {
        holder.myCheckBox.setChecked(true);
        holder.myItem.setPaintFlags(holder.myItem.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        holder.myItem.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#8C000000"));
    }
    else {
        holder.myCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        holder.myItem.setPaintFlags( holder.myItem.getPaintFlags() & (~ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG) );
        holder.myItem.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#E6000000"));
    }
}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}

// Implement OnClick listener.
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    if (holder.myCheckBox.isChecked()) {
        Task task = mDataset.get(holder.getPosition());
        task.setCompleted(true);
        mDataset.set(holder.getPosition(), task);
    }
    else {
        Task task = mDataset.get(holder.getPosition());
        task.setCompleted(false);
        mDataset.set(holder.getPosition(), task);
    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

            if (view.getText().length() != 0) {
                Task task = mDataset.get(holder.getPosition());
                task.setName(view.getText().toString());
                mDataset.set(holder.getPosition(), task);

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                view.setText("");
            }

            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Create the ViewHolder class to keep references to your views
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public LinearLayout myRow;
    public CheckBox myCheckBox;
    public EditText myItem;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param v The container view which holds the elements from the item_row.xml
     */
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        myRow = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.item_row);
        myCheckBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.myCheckBox);
        myItem = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.myItem);
    }
}
```

From your activity you can use them like this:

```
yourAdapter.getDataSet(); // return your adapter data
yourAdapter.setDataSet(newData); // change your adapter data
```

Comment: I already tried this. The issue I get is that in my activity, when I type yourAdapter.getDataSet(), Android Studio throws an error stating "cannot resolve method getDataSet()".

Comment: are you sure that *yourAdapter* is an instance of MyCustomAdapter?

Comment: Yes. This is what it looks like in my activity.

`RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(MyActivity.this, listOfData);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
ArrayList<Task> testList = adapter.getDataSet(); // cannot resolve method`

Comment: That's strange! try to rebuild your project. Otherwise change mDataset to public and get his value by adapter.mDataset;

Comment: I cleaned the project and then tried to rebuild and it failed. Got the following error `Error:(96, 39) error: cannot find symbol method getDataSet()`. The same happens when I make mDataset public and try to access it using adapter.mDataset

Comment: it works when you rebuild it at the first time and then when you clean & rebuild the project it fails?

Comment: No sorry, I posted the comment about it working before the rebuild was complete. I have fixed the issue however. In my activity I had the following `RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(...)` but with this only methods from RecyclerView.Adapter are accessible. I then changed it to `MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(...)` and then I had access to the method. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Rami A life saver. Simple and quick, done it within a minute.

Answer (score 3):

Rami's answer is almost correct, all he needs to cast.
You need to cast the instance of the adapter to your adapter in order to access the method. This is what you can do in your activity:

```
((MyCustomAdapter)mAdapter).setDataSet(newData);
```

If mAdapter is the instance you created in your activity and setDataSet is the public function of the MyCustomAdapter class.

Cheers!